# I want to align some sentences using css

Tags: html, css

```
                 this is my alignment :
             this is my alignment one :
         this is my alignment one two :
   this is my alignment one two three :

style="position:absolute;top:63px;left:151px;width:88px;margin-left:-132px;margin-top:5px"

<span id="resultModel.hdPk1Label" name="resultModel.hdPk1Label" class="singleFormLabel" style="position:absolute;top:36px;left:151px;width:88px;margin-left:-132px;margin-top:5px"><font class="essential_mark">*</font>label.hdPk1 &nbsp;:&nbsp;</span>
```

I have some elements/labels & i want to arrange/align them in above manner and using the above code but its aligning it as shown below :

```
this is my alignment :
this is my alignment one :
this is my alignment one two :
this is my alignment one two three :
```

How can I achieve my desired result?

Comment: `text-align: right`?

Comment: You may want to include the HTML for said "elements/labels" you want to arrange, or it could be harder for us to understand your difficulties.

Comment: please send us an example of your markup. ie. jsfiddle.net and tell us your restrictions. is it allowed to add maybe <span> elements around your phrases?

Comment: @ Jack Black: edited and added the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what you describe, you're just looking for `text-align: right;`:

```css
span
{
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: pre;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<span>
  this is my alignment :
  this is my alignment one :
  this is my alignment one two :
  this is my alignment one two three :
</span>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<div class="right">this is my alignment :<br/>
     this is my alignment one :<br/>
 this is my alignment one two :</div>
```

css

```
.right
{
    text-align:right;
}
```

fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/oa7tbcgj/

Comment: `<br/>`, not `</br>`.

Comment: style="position:absolute;top:97px;left:170px;width:48px;margin-left:-132px;text-align: right;margin-top:5px"                                                        its not affecting the indentation

Comment: actually every label is kept in different "span" and width of every "Label" is different , then how it will right align the texts as every "label" is kept in different "span"

Answer (score 1):

See code:

```css
div {
  position:absolute;
  /* top:63px; adding your top margin of 5px from this value gives you a new property of... */
  top:68px
    
  /* left:151px; subtracting your negative left margin of 132px from this value gives you a new property of... */
  left: 19px;
  
  /* width:88px; 88px is not wide enough for standard font size to make lines at this length */
  width:250px;
 
  text-align:right; /* aligns text to the right instead of to the left */
  
  /* Don't use margins on positioned elements unless you're trying to 'hack' something to be centered relative to some percentage position (ex left:50%; margin-left:-(half of this block's explicit width)). When you use positioning and margins you can no longer look at a single property declaration (ie "margin-top" or "left") to determine the positioning of your element. That makes maintaining your code more difficult and planning your layout around your positioned element more complicated. */
  /* margin-left:-132px; */
  /* margin-top:5px; */
}

p {
  /* paragraph tags, by default, have a top and bottom margin of 1em. We need to overwrite this default to get your lines to stack like you want them to */
  margin:0;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <p>this is my alignment :</p>
  <p>this is my alignment one :</p>
  <p>this is my alignment one two :</p>
  <p>this is my alignment one two three :</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/esc0se6x/

HTML

```
<div class="right">
    <span id="resultModel.hdPk1Label" name="label1" class="singleFormLabel">label.hdPk1 &nbsp;:&nbsp;</span>
    <span id="resultModel.hdPk1Label" name="label2" class="singleFormLabel">loremloremdPk1 &nbsbsp;dPk1 &nbsp;:&nbsp;</span>
    <span id="resultModel.hdPk1Label" name="label3" class="singleFormLabel">label.loremdPk1 &nbsbsp;:&nbsp;hdPk1 &nbsp;:&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.right {
    text-align:right;
}

.right > span {
    display:block;
}
```